# Addressing Main Storage: What is the difference between D(B) and D(X,B)?

Tags: assembly

Addressing Main Storage: What is the difference between D(B) and D(X,B) ?

Can you please explain this in simple terms...  I am trying to understand what the difference between them is . I know X = index register and B = base register..

I guess i am confused or not understanding what the difference between an index register and a base register is..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction is most interesting when there is also a scale involved.

I'll use Intel syntax here because that's what I am most familiar with.

If you have an instruction on the form

```
mov eax, [ebx+esi*4]
```

Then that generalizes to

```
instr target, [base+index*scale]
```

Base, then, hold the address where the array (typically) is located in memory, index is the zero-based array element number in the array, and scale is 1, 2, or 4, depending on whether it's an array of bytes, words, or dwords.